# How can I reuse the same std::vector variable in C++?

Tags: c++, multithreading, memory-management, vector, memory-leaks

I have a bunch of integer vectors and array of integer vectors, that will have to be cleared and updated in each iteration.

I am running into memory leak errors like "munmap_chunk() invalid pointer" "free(): invalid next size (fast):" "double free or corruption" as I
am unable to clear/manage memory efficiently.

Program:

```
vector<vector<int>> work_queue;
vector<int> global_graph[NUM_OF_NODES];
vector<int> global_L0;
vector<int> global_L1;
vector<int> global_L2;

main thread
-----------
while(!exit) {
// update output using results stored in global vector

//clear workqueue
    for (int m = 0; m < NUM_OF_WORKERS; m++) {
        work_queue[m].clear();
    }

// update workqueue using updated results
    for (int m = 0; m < NUM_OF_WORKERS; m++) {
        work_queue.push_back(row);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < source_vertices.size(); i++) {
        work_queue[i % NUM_OF_WORKERS].push_back(source_vertices[i]);
    }

// clear global vectors - free memory
    global_L0.clear();
    global_L1.clear();
    global_L2.clear();

//call worker threads

}

 All worker threads execute the below function
    --------------------------------------------
    void * worker() {
        vector<int> local_graph[NUM_OF_NODES];
        vector<int> local_L0;
        vector<int> local_L1;
        vector<int> local_L2
        while (1) {
        // clear all local vectors; free memory 
            local_L0.clear();
            local_L1.clear();
            local_L2.clear();
            while (!work_queue[workerId].empty) {
                // do the calculations based on global data and update local vectors
                // threads synchronize and update global vectors 
                // based on local computations on local vectors
                // when done loop through
            }
        //check_thread for exit condition() and break if required;
        }
    }
```

What am I missing here? Why is there a memory leak in this program structure?
Appreciate your help. Thanks

Comment: vectors aren't thread-safe.

Comment: yep! I have local vectors in each thread and I have synchronization points where the threads update global vectors. I have the programs results correct for small no. of nodes but when I increase the node size my program runs into memory leaks as no. of iterations increase and data structures grow big.

Comment: As it has been said, STL vectors are not thread-safe. Access to those global vectors, including the work_queue vector of vectors, must be protected by mutex(es) [not sure if that's what you mean by *synchronization point*]. Access means all the places where there's a read or a write access, in all the worker threads and the main thread. You should add to your question your actual locking/synchronization code if you want get any meaningful answer.

Comment: @jsantander Sure. Can such synchronization errors also cause memory leaks? My program produces correct results for small no of nodes. But when increased no. of nodes my code throws memory errors. Hence I dint concentrate  on the synchronization part.

Comment: Well, from a generic point of view STL structures have some degree of complexity, if two threads try to update them at the same time, the internals might get out of sync, leading to memory not properly handled or pointers left pointed to wrong places... so yes, synchronization errors can cause memory leaks, core dumps, your computer to explode or to develop its own personality.

Comment: It's likely the code you haven't shown us is causing the issue.  You should flesh out your example.  Reducing your code to a smaller example may also help you find the issue as long as you do it in such a way that you can tell when you've removed the part causing the issue or when the behavior changes.

Comment: @jsantander oh ok thanks. I dint realize that. But even after adding locks I still get memory errors.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Yep makes sense. Will do that. I was wondering If i was doing wrong something very basic in the above outline of declarations and  vector clears.